# light ray 'entropy'

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Is there something like an entropy law for light rays?

I came up with the following experiment: A black box has two circular holes in it, a small and a large one. I don't care about there placement. Now I like to build something into the box that any ray entering the large hole will exit the box through the small hole.

However, I could not imagine any combination of optical tools like lenses, mirrors and so on that would do that.

It seems possible to concentrate a parallel bundle of light to a small spot or hole, but not unordered rays.

Is there a law written in ink that forbids such a contraption?

Comment: There is indeed, excellent intuition! This is called conservation of etendue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue

Comment: Thanks! If you post that as an answer, I will accept it. An addition: If I would use a solar cell and an electrical lightsource both highly effective, it should be possible to build the box. Is this possible becuase it's by non-optic means, or is there a deeper law that would limit the effectivenes of the cell or the source to impede this?

Comment: @dronus It is possible because transfer entropy somewhere else. In fact you need some energy to erase information, but its negligible.

Comment: Perhaps @zephyr should submit an answer to this question so that this moves out of the 'unanswered' section?

Comment: BTW Because the entropy of light is entropy like any other, you can trade it for other kinds of entropy. So if you don't mind producing some heat as a side effect, you *can* concentrate light further than you can with lenses and mirrors if you interpret 'concentrate' liberally enough. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminescent_solar_concentrator

Comment: What if I connect the two holes with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber ?

Comment: Still holds.. the fiber has to be conical, as the size of the two holes differ. The fiber then would then reflect some of the light entering the large hole back to the large hole, and widens the angle between beams exiting the small hole in respect to the angle of rays at the large hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I'm copy-pasting from @user2963's [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/light-ray-entropy/74214#comment54004_23383) into this community wiki.)*

> There is indeed, excellent intuition! This is called conservation of
>   etendue. [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue)